# Transpose n column in excel with macro VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Greeting 
   I am new to VBA and excel . I need to transpose N column from a sheet to another sheet with a macro .PS I need a macro not using the predefine copy and paste transpose in excel and thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Transpose_Data_From_Vertical_To_Horizontal()
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim sh          As Worksheet
Dim arr         As Variant

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
arr = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("N1:N" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 
14).End(xlUp).Row).Value)

sh.Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(arr)).Value = arr
End Sub
```